# Perl - how to handle multiple check boxes?

Tags: perl

I´am searching for a solution to handle a form in Perl with multiple checkboxes. Following issue:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2">
.....
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="500">
```

In the script:

```
$q = new CGI;
my $checkbox = $q->param("checkbox");
foreach ( CHECKED_CHECKBOXES )
{ do something  }
```

I have no idea how to read out all checked checkboxes. May somebody an idea for me?

Comment: Let's start with this: what's _not_ working with your current code? What is your expected output? What is your actual output?

Comment: If I check the first checkbox - than `$checkbox == 1`. If I check the second or the third one also the $checkbox is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `param` in list context.

```
my @checkboxes = $q->param("checkbox");
```

Comment: I forget what happens if one checkbox is selected.  Will this still work since it should return a scalar?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Here's the code to return one scalar: `PUSHs(sv)`. Here's the code to return a list of one scalar: `PUSHs(sv)`. They're the same. That's because the words "list of" is purely fluff. There's  nothing being returned except scalars.